# How to know which field is to update in a MVC view?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

i am working on a Java Swing Application that uses the MVC Design Pattern. The Main View has a Model associated with it, where the program logic is done. Via setChanged() and NotifyObservers() in the Setters, the View is notified. In the View, there is the implementation of a method

```
public void update(Observable o, Object arg)
```

that handles the Update of the View. But how do i know in the update-Method which field in the view is to update? o is the Model itself, and arg can be the parameter of NotifyObservers(Object).

But say i have three int-values in the model, that need to be shown in the view. If i compare

```
if (o.field1 == arg) {
   ...
} else if (o.field2 == arg) {
   ...
}
```

it does not compare if it is the field, but it compares the value of the integers, so the developer does not know which field is to update.

So I could do two things:

1. Using Integer (not int) and if i want to compare the value, i use .equals(Integer) and giving the object of Integer to NotifyChanged. But i have to remember that in the Model i have to compare with the method of the class, and in other parts of my program i have to compare via ==, so i maybe dont know which method is to use.
2. Passing a String with the Name of the variable - maybe a global constant - to NotifyChanged().

What is the correct and recommended way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could either use method #2 (passing the name of the variable), which is a common thing to do for simple variable changes.  However, in general, you would likely have several callback methods like your ```update``` method, that indicate that different events have occurred.  For example, if the user presses a button, there isn't really much to pass to the ```update``` method; so you would likely add a new method to your callback interface along the lines of ```buttonPressed()```.

Comment: "The Main View has a Model associated with it, where the program logic is done." This is not MVC. In MVC, there is no direct connection between Model and View. Communication is solely done through the controller. Also, your Model should only hold values, no logic. The logic is part of the Controller.

Answer (score 1):

When I create a Swing MVC application, I follow 3 simple rules.

- The view reads values from the model.
- The view does not update the model.
- The controller(s) update the model and refresh / repaint the view.

The model does not know about the view or controller.

Here's a really simple Swing application that uses the MVC pattern.

[image]

The Swing application generates 4 random numbers.  Each number has a color associated with the number.

The DataModel class defines a number / color value.  The DisplayModel class creates a List of DataModels.  The list contains 4 instances of DataModel.

This List is sorted and passed to the view.  When you left click on the New Numbers button, a new set of 4 number / color is generated and passed to the view.

Here's the code:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SortFrames implements Runnable {

    private DisplayModel displayModel;

    private JPanel[] panels;

    private JLabel[] labels;

    public SortFrames() {
        this.displayModel = new DisplayModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<DataModel> dataModels = displayModel.getDisplayModel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sort Frames");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        panels = new JPanel[dataModels.size()];
        labels = new JLabel[dataModels.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < dataModels.size(); i++) {
            DataModel dataModel = dataModels.get(i);
            panels[i] = new JPanel();
            panels[i].setBackground(dataModel.getBackgroundColor());
            panels[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));

            labels[i] = new JLabel(getDisplayText(dataModel));
            labels[i].setBackground(dataModel.getBackgroundColor());
            labels[i].setForeground(dataModel.getForegroundColor());

            panels[i].add(labels[i]);
            mainPanel.add(panels[i]);
        }

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        JButton submitButton = new JButton("New Numbers");
        submitButton.addActionListener(new SubmitActionListener(displayModel,
                this));

        buttonPanel.add(submitButton);

        frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void update() {
        List<DataModel> dataModels = displayModel.getDisplayModel();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataModels.size(); i++) {
            DataModel dataModel = dataModels.get(i);

            panels[i].setBackground(dataModel.getBackgroundColor());

            labels[i].setBackground(dataModel.getBackgroundColor());
            labels[i].setForeground(dataModel.getForegroundColor());
            labels[i].setText(getDisplayText(dataModel));
        }
    }

    private String getDisplayText(DataModel dataModel) {
        if (dataModel.getNumber() == 12) {
            return "-";
        } else {
            return Integer.toString(dataModel.getNumber());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SortFrames());
    }

    public class DisplayModel {

        private Random random;

        private List<DataModel> displayModel;

        public DisplayModel() {
            this.displayModel = new ArrayList<>();
            this.random = new Random();
            createDisplayModel();
        }

        public void createDisplayModel() {
            displayModel.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                int number = random.nextInt(13);
                int colorNumber = random.nextInt(2);
                Color backgroundColor = Color.BLACK;
                Color foregroundColor = Color.WHITE;
                if (colorNumber == 1) {
                    backgroundColor = Color.WHITE;
                    foregroundColor = Color.BLACK;
                }
                displayModel.add(new DataModel(number, colorNumber,
                        backgroundColor, foregroundColor));
            }

            Collections.sort(displayModel, new DataModelComparator());
        }

        public List<DataModel> getDisplayModel() {
            return displayModel;
        }

    }

    public class DataModel {
        private final int number;
        private final int colorNumber;

        private final Color backgroundColor;
        private final Color foregroundColor;

        public DataModel(int number, int colorNumber, Color backgroundColor,
                Color foregroundColor) {
            this.number = number;
            this.colorNumber = colorNumber;
            this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
            this.foregroundColor = foregroundColor;
        }

        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public int getColorNumber() {
            return colorNumber;
        }

        public Color getBackgroundColor() {
            return backgroundColor;
        }

        public Color getForegroundColor() {
            return foregroundColor;
        }

    }

    public class DataModelComparator implements Comparator<DataModel> {

        @Override
        public int compare(DataModel o1, DataModel o2) {
            if (o1.getNumber() < o2.getNumber()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (o1.getNumber() > o2.getNumber()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                if (o1.getColorNumber() < o2.getColorNumber()) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (o1.getColorNumber() > o2.getColorNumber()) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class SubmitActionListener implements ActionListener {

        private DisplayModel displayModel;

        private SortFrames sortFrames;

        public SubmitActionListener(DisplayModel displayModel,
                SortFrames sortFrames) {
            this.displayModel = displayModel;
            this.sortFrames = sortFrames;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            displayModel.createDisplayModel();
            sortFrames.update();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: One would argue that in a "proper" MVC, the view and model NEVER know about each other and that the controller binds the two together, but I've seen MVC mutated so many different ways, it pretty much comes down to anything goes :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer: It's not "anything goes".  The model remains ignorant of the view and controller so you can change the view and controller from Swing to a web front end.  If the view is ignorant of the model, the controller(s) has (have) too much work to do, in my opinion.

Comment: At the end of the day, the intention is to get to a point where the model, controller and view and independent of each others implementation, so you can change any one and the intention of the system remains intact. Not saying your approach is wrong, just saying that I've seen it done in many different ways :P - Your approach is much closer to how Swing is implemented, where as iOS uses an approach where the model and view know nothing about each other and the controller is the binding between the two ;)